# Simple C++ container class that is thread-safe for writing

Tags: c++, data-structures, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I am writing a multi-threaded program using OpenMP in C++.  At one point my program forks into many threads, each of which need to add "jobs" to some container that keeps track of all added jobs.  Each job can just be a pointer to some object.

**Basically, I just need the add pointers to some container from several threads at the same time.**

Is there a simple solution that performs well?  After some googling, I found that STL containers are not thread-safe.  Some [stackoverflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048806/implementing-a-thread-safe-generic-stack-in-c-on-linux) address this question, but none that forms a consensus on a simple solution.

Comment: Unless you have very specific usage requirements, you're almost always better off with any type of container other than list. `std::deque` and `std::vector` are much better in the vast majority of cases. (`std::stack` is implemented using a `deque` by default)

Comment: TBB provides some -> http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. You can simply use a lock to guard one of the existing container types. It might be a better idea to have each thread use it's own container, then combine the results together in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using a mutex or similar synchronization primitive to control access to a linked list is not very difficult, so I'd recommend you try that first.

If it performs so poorly that you can't use it, try this instead: give each thread its own job queue, and have the job consumer check all the queues in turn.  This way each queue has only one reader and one writer, so a lock-free implementation is relatively straightforward.  By this I mean it may exist for your platform; you should not attempt to write it yourself.